# Can I put an expression in a separate module to update the form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Expressions:

```
Forms![Frm_MainForm]![Frm_SubForm_1].Requery  
Forms![Frm_MainForm]![Frm_SubForm_2].Requery
```

I use multiple database forms.
Can I put these expressions in a separate module and call the procedure for updating forms in different parts of the database?

For example in the module "md_Requery":

```
Public UpdateForm()
Forms![Frm_MainForm]![Frm_SubForm_1].Requery
Forms![Frm_MainForm]![Frm_SubForm_2].Requery
End sub
```

[image]

Comment: It's Public _Sub_ UpdateForms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Public UpdateForm()` is valid in the `(Delarations)` section of a module: it declares a public `Variant` array named `UpdateForm`.

That makes the body of the procedure illegal though, because `[thing].Requery` is an executable statement, that's illegal outside of a procedure's scope.

Change the declaration to read `Public Sub UpdateForm()`, and you'll notice the top-right dropdown will change from `(Declarations)` to `UpdateForm`, indicating that you're inside a procedure scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this public procedure in the module:

```
Public Sub RequeryForm(frmName As String)
    Dim frm As Form
    If IsLoaded(frmName) then
        Set frm = Forms(frmName)
        frm.Requery
    End If
End Sub

Public Function IsLoaded(frmName as String)
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    'to call this function, you must put the form in quotes: IsLoaded("frmEntries_EntrySelection")    
    IsLoaded = (SysCmd(SYSCMD_GETOBJECTSTATE, A_FORM, FormName) <> 0)

Exit_Procedure:
    Exit Function
Error_Handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description
            Resume Exit_Procedure
            Resume
    End Select
End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
RequeryForm "Frm_SubForm_1"
```